# How can I access mongodb count results in nodejs with a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

How do you access mongodb count results in nodejs so the result can be accessible to the asynchronous request? I can get the result and update the database but the asynchronous request fails to access the vars or the vars are empty and the vars appear to be updated when the next asynchronous request is made. The request must not be waiting for the query to finish and the next request is filled with the previous request's variables.

```
testOne.increment = function(request) {   
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bbb_tracking', function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    collection = db.collection('bbb_tio');
        collection.count({vio_domain:dom}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;                                     
    if (docs > 0) {
            var vio_val = 3;                                        
        } else {
            var vio_val = 0;                    
        }                   
        if (vio_val === 3) {
                event = "New_Event";
        var inf = 3;
            }                                       
        db.close();

        console.log("docs " + docs);
        });       
   });                    
};
```

In the above, even when the vars are set in scope they are not defined asynchronously. Can I get some guidance on structuring this properly so the vars are populated in the callback.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I changed the question to "How can I access mongodb count results in nodejs with a callback?" I cannot get the var results into a callback that waits for the query to finish. Does that help? Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `count` function is asynchronous, you'll need to pass a callback to the `increment` function so that when the `count` is returned from the database, the code can call the callback.

```
testOne.increment = function(request, callback) {   
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bbb_tracking', function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var collection = db.collection('bbb_tio');
        // not sure where the dom value comes from ?
        collection.count({vio_domain:dom}, function(err, count) {
            var vio_val = 0;
            if (err) throw err;                                     
            if (count > 0) {
                vio_val = 3;                                        
                event = "New_Event";
                var inf = 3;
            }                                       
            db.close();

            console.log("docs count: " + count);        
           // call the callback here (err as the first parameter, and the value as the second)
           callback(null, count);   
        });       
   });                 
};

testOne.increment({}, function(err, count) {
   // the count would be here...
});
```

*(I don't understand what the variables you've used mean or why they're not used later, so I just did a bit of a clean-up. Variables are scoped to function blocks and hoisted to the function, so you don't need to redeclare them in each if block like you had done with `vio_val`).*

Comment: Hello WiredPirate.  Thank you so much!  I am trying this now.

Comment: error on callback(null, docs);    
     
ReferenceError: docs is not defined  Working on it now.

Comment: What? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: It is throwing and error, docs is not defined, on callback(null, docs);, the last callback.

Comment: I tweaked my code to use a different variable name, but the code above should work fine if the concept is copied correctly to your code. The `docs`/`count` variable should be the name of the parameter passed to the callback for the `count` function. If you don't have the callback in the right block, it won't work, and you'd get that error.

Comment: Roger that.  Thank you so much! I am getting it going now.  I will let you know in a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. Thank you so much for your time and effort WiredPrairie! You are very good at this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'async' module. It makes the code a lot cleaner and easier to debug. Take a look at the code in GitHub for adduser.js & deleteuser.js in the following post

http://gigadom.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/bend-it-like-bluemix-mongodb-using-auto-scaling-part-2/

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

length give you count of result array

```
  const userdata = await User.find({ role: role, 'name': new RegExp(searchkey, 'i')  },{date: 0,__v:0,password:0}).
      sort(orderObj)
      .limit(limit)
      .skip(skip);



      console.log(userdata.length);
```